# PNP Transistor question

Tags: transistors, pnp

I am studying for my circuits exam and in the review we have this question below:

The output of a PNP transistor used as a switch is normally taken off it’s ____________ terminal.

I would say collector terminal because of the nature of the PNP transistor.

This is a traditional PNP transistor that our professor draws:

[image]

Comment: Draw your circuit using the schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: I mean this is a transistor (above), but I would like to believe it is the collector terminal.

Comment: @diegogmx What are you trying to say, that the source of an NMOS transistor is used as its "output"?

Comment: oops, small lapsus, you would actually connect the load in the drain in both cases, in pnp and npn also the collector, as they get "flipped"

Comment: The arrow on BJTs (and diodes), point in the direction of positive current flow...

Comment: @JorgeJuarez You are fine with your answer. That's most situations, anyway. No one can speak for all.

Comment: That's not a circuit. That's just the symbol for a PNP transistor and you can assume that we all know that. We're prompting you to draw the circuit for a "*PNP transistor used as a switch*". You need to show where the supply is connected and where the load is connected. You can use the schematic button on the editor toolbar.